# Ajax based chat - infinite server side loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http-post

I have a chat on my page. I send the ajax post every 5 seconds to check the replies. Isn't there any better solution for it to avoid the sending too many requests?

Something like the infinite* loop on server.

PHP server side:

```
$i = 0
while(!$replies = checkNewReplies() && $i++<1000){        
    sleep(1);
}
echo json_encode($replies);
exit;
```

Wrong approach?

Comment: long polling  ..? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: COMET style programing, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) will give you the available aproaches (long polling be most populaur)

Comment: And what about websocket?

Comment: Search for Websockest I/O and node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are number of possible solutions. You could look at long-polling (which is basically what you are doing).

Another alternative is to use something like XMPP which has some Javascript clients.

Answer (score 0):

This page will definitely help you, it helped me integrate a fully real-time messaging system within an internal sales dashboard I developed....very cool stuff.

http://www.aljtmedia.com/blog/websockets-for-php-ratchet-push-chat-application?article=24#.UcNxNfmkoSU

Answer (score 0):

One thing that i think Facebook does well is, they use long polling when the text input has `focus`. They open that connection until the input is `blur`-red. Which makes me think that they have some DOM Event listener waiting to open and close a connection. Long polling is tricky, as it can  create havoc on your server. You must ensure that when the body `onload` you shut off all connections that may have been opened.

Your approach sounds reasonable, but if your pulling in the data from a database, and your comfortable enough with the amount of calls going to the db, then you might use `usleep()` rather than `sleep()`. You could always use something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) for your SQL statements.

This is all opinionated though.